# How to transfer django model field data to another field

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a Django app in which I have videos. The description field for a video is set to CharField but I would like to change it to TextField. I don’t want to lose the data from my CharField but instead transfer it over to my TextField. How would I go about doing so?

Comment: Change the field definition from `CharField` to `TextField`, and run as a migration.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to change CharField into TextField in models.py file.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    description = models.TextField(max_length=200)
```

and set your max_length for the field.